# Springboot 2.7.2 to 3.0.7 upgrade and profile loading is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As part of sprinboot upgrade 2.7.2 to
Version : **3.0.7**

**Context :**

Spring boot was unable to load the profile specific properties

src/main/resources/application-it.properties and **application-couchbase-it.properties**

Contents of application-it.properties

`spring.profiles.group.it=couchbase-it-reno, .....`

But Springboot Was unable to load the application-couchbase-it.properties which is also present in the src/main/resources

When I was resolving the **spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts** it was null

**Question :**

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this breaking changes ?

Comment: Could you provide some repository with simple reproduce?

Comment: The profile groups should be defined in `application.properties`.  Also, you truncated your property, but according to your couchbase profile, it's couchbase-it-reno, yet your property file is named couchbase-it.properties.  The properties file name needs to correspond to the profile name, e.g. couchbase-it-reno.properties.

Comment: @lane.maxwell ya both the files like application-couchbase-it-reno.properties and application-couchbase.properties are present on src/main/resources ..sorry if any typos ..Still i didnt get resolution even from chatgpt :) so finally am here